# Python: Make Reference to Another Variable

Tags: python

I have a class instance `instance_1`.

How can I create another variable that always holds an up to date reference to `instance_1`?

This one does not work:

```
class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_a = 44

    def update_my_a(self):
        self.my_a = 33


instance_1 = my_class()
my_var = instance_1.my_a
instance_1.update_my_a()
print(instance_1.my_a)
>>33
print(my_var)
>>44
```

Comment: Everything is a reference in Python. However, assignment merely rebinds the reference to the name. So, make your value a mutable type (class Val: ...) then mutate it in `update_my_a`, e.g. `self.my_a_val.set(33)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create object reference like below

```
class my_class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.my_a = 44

    def update_my_a(self):
        self.my_a = 33


instance_1 = my_class()
my_var = instance_1
instance_1.update_my_a()
print(instance_1.my_a)
>33
print(my_var.my_a)
>33
```